# Question about integral properties

Tags: definite-integrals

Been stuck on this one for a while now. Any help would be appreciated:

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be an integrable function. Prove that there exist a $c\in[a,b]$ such that:

$$\int_a^c f(x)dx=\int_c^b f(x)dx$$

Comment: Can you use the fact that the indefinite integral, $\int_a^x f(t)dt$, is a continuous function?  If so then you can use the "intermediate value property".

Comment: Yes, it'ts implied from the fundamental theorem of calculus. I see now how I can use the intermediate value property, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be defined by $F(x):=\int_a^x f(t)dt -\int_x^b f(t) dt$ for $a \le x \le b.$

Then we have:

$F$ is continuous, $F(b)=\int_a^b f(t)dt$ and $F(a)=-\int_a^b f(t)dt=-F(b).$

Hence there is $c \in [a,b]$ such that $F(c)=0$.

Comment: Hi, thanks alot. if I understand correctly you used the intermediate value property?